# Jenkins Plugin > Require restart on update?

Tags: java, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I'm currently developing a Jenkins plugin, and am experiencing an issue when users update the plugin, whereby changes don't take effect until the plugin/Jenkins is restarted.

As a plugin developer, is there anyway I can get Jenkins to not activate the plugin, until Jenkins is restarted?

i.e. Replicate the behaviour of other plugins, that show:

```
"Downloaded Successfully. Will be activated during the next boot"
```

Comment: side note: If I was aware that your plugin attempted to force a Jenkins restart anytime it updated I'd avoid it like the plague. It's not always feasible to grab an update for a plugin and immediately be able to restart Jenkins given the number and size of the builds we (and presumably many others) run.

Comment: Thanks, I agree. Not looking to force the Jenkins to restart immediatly, just wishing to replicate the behaviour of other plugins, which when downloaded say: `Downloaded Successfully. Will be activated during the next boot`.